# CSS border top is hiding text

Tags: css, tabs, css-shapes

I'm trying to create a trapezoid shape with tabs, though like any corporate workplace, it needs to be a certain way. I'm able to create a trapezoid shape with my tabs with the larger side on the bottom, though when I try to flip it around, the text is hidden, and I am lost as to why this is.

I've created a plunkr to show you. I have the `border-bottom` commented out in the CSS file, and I'm using the `border-top` attribute by default.

https://plnkr.co/edit/6O7UHJXUZrmJ4ZGTRTy5

```css
/* Styles go here */

.tabs {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.tabs li {
  float: left;
}
.tabs li a {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 4px;
  height: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  /* choose border-top or border-bottom */
  /*border bottom works*/
  /*border-bottom: 30px solid #e9eaeb;*/
  /*border top hides text*/
  border-top: 30px solid #e9eaeb;
  color: black;
}
.tabs li a:hover {
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 30px solid #87898b;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class='tabs'>
  <li><a href='#'>Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href='#'>About Us</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href='#'>Blog</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Stupid question, but are the texts always supposed to be visible? Simply removing the `overflow:hidden` achieves that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why does the text not show up when border top is used instead of border bottom?**

It is a combination of multiple things - (1) the `height: 0px` on the element (2) how text is positioned in the box when it has only borders and no height (3) the `line-height: 30px` on the element and (4) the `overflow: hidden` that is applied to the parent.

Before I go into more details, please have a look at the below snippet. I have added different colors to each of the four borders for the purpose of illustration. I have also added a background to the first line to show where exactly the line of text is.

```css
/* Styles go here */

.tabs {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.tabs li {
  float: left;
}
.tabs li a {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 4px;
  height: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
.tabs.sample li a {
  border-left: 15px solid red;
  border-right: 15px solid blue;
  border-top: 30px solid #e9eaeb;
  border-bottom: 30px solid yellow;
}
.tabs.sample.a li a {
  line-height: 30px;
}
.tabs.sample li a::first-line {
  background: cyan;
}
.tabs li a:hover {
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: 30px solid #87898b;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h3>With Line Height 30px</h3>
<ul class='tabs sample a'>
  <li><a href='#'>Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href='#'>About Us</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href='#'>Blog</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<h3>Without Line Height</h3>
<ul class='tabs sample b'>
  <li><a href='#'>Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href='#'>About Us</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href='#'>Blog</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When the box only has borders but no height (`0px`) and , the text within the box is positioned (loose usage of the word, it doesn't refer to the `position` attribute) in such a way that the text is below the top border but above the bottom border.

The parent `.tabs` element has no explicit `height` defined for it. This means that this element would be as tall as its contents. Content height is calculated as element's height + its border height because it has the default `box-sizing` (which is `content-box`) and this means borders are not part of defined height. So, the element's height (and its parent's height) are 30px irrespective of whether it has border on top or on bottom. `overflow: hidden` setting implies that anything below 30px height will be hidden.

When the element only has bottom border (that is, top border is 0px), the text gets shown because it is on top of the bottom border and so `overflow: hidden` on the parent doesn't affect it. When it has only top border, the text is actually below it (meaning it is below the 30px point) and so it gets clipped.

**Will adding height or removing the overflow setting on parent solve the problem?**

**NO**, it would not solve the problem if you **want the text on top of the shape** (or in other words, look as though it is inside the shape). This is because the text still remains below the top border and none of these settings will change it.

**What are the solutions when using this approach for creating the shape?**

- You could wrap the content within a `span` element that is positioned on top of the `a` element with a negative margin that is equal to the `border-top-width`.

  ```css
  /* Styles go here */

  .tabs {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
  }
  .tabs li {
    float: left;
  }
  .tabs li a {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 4px;
    height: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    line-height: 30px;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-top: 30px solid #e9eaeb;
  }
  .tabs li a span{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -30px; /* equal to border top * -1 */
  }
  .tabs li a:hover {
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-top: 30px solid #87898b;
    color: white;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <ul class='tabs'>
    <li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'><span>About Us</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'><span>Blog</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  ```
- You could use an extra element that is absolutely positioned like in Mojtaba Hn's answer also.

**Are there any other alternate approaches?**

Yes, there are a couple of other alternates using CSS `transform` or SVG.

- Using CSS Transforms:

  ```css
  /* Styles go here */

  .tabs {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
  }
  .tabs li {
    float: left;
  }
  .tabs li a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 20px;
    height: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
  .tabs li a:before,
  .tabs li a:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    top: 0px;
    background: #e9eaeb;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  .tabs li a:before {
    left: 0px;
    transform: skew(30deg);
    transform-origin: left top;
  }
  .tabs li a:after {
    right: 0px;
    transform: skew(-30deg);
    transform-origin: right top;
  }
  .tabs li a:hover:before,
  .tabs li a:hover:after {
    background: #87898b;
    color: white;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <ul class='tabs'>
    <li><a href='#'>Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Blog</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  ```
- Using SVG:

  ```css
  /* Styles go here */

  .tabs {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
  }
  .tabs li {
    float: left;
  }
  .tabs li a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
  .tabs li a svg {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 0px;
  }
  .tabs li a svg use {
    fill: #e9eaeb;
  }
  .tabs li a:hover svg use{
    fill: #87898b;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <svg width='0' height='0' viewBox='0 0 10 3' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
    <path d='M0,0 10,0 8,3 2,3z' id='shape' />
  </svg>
  <ul class='tabs'>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>
        <svg viewBox='0 0 10 3' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
          <use xlink:href='#shape' />
        </svg>
        Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>
        <svg viewBox='0 0 10 3' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
          <use xlink:href='#shape' />
        </svg>
        About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>
        <svg viewBox='0 0 10 3' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
          <use xlink:href='#shape' />
        </svg>
        Blog</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the options I would have to resolve this!

Answer (score 1):

take a look at what I made : https://jsfiddle.net/mojtabaa_hn/vppnrw6e/

I'm a little confused about the part you said `I'm able to create a trapezoid shape with my tabs with the larger side on the bottom`. take a look anyway.

Comment: I need it flipped vertically, where the longest side of the trapezoid is on the top.

Answer (score 0):

Change `height:0` to `height:30px`, and add `height:0` to the hover class.